# How do I hide my username in irc?

Tags: irc, hostname, irssi

I'm using irssi for my IRC client, and whenever I connect to a channel (e.g., `#whatwg`), it greets me with the line and I've tried the command line

```
0:22 -!- <nick> [~kalaracey@12.345.678.90] has joined #whatwg
```

I do not want my real <del>hostname</del> username there (i.e., `kalaracey`). How do I change this, so that `kalaracey` isn't there; i.e., everybody doesn't match that name with my IP.

<del>I've tried
`irssi --hostname=<hostname>` and `irssi -h <hostname`. I've also done, inside irssi, `/set hostname <hostname>` and, when adding a server, `/server add -host <hostname> -network <network> <address>`.</del>

EDIT: Just realized what I want to hide is my username, NOT my hostname. Thanks @DaveC.

Comment: Isn't that your username not hostname?

Comment: Try /username WHATEVER

Comment: if the problem is name and IP association, `/mode your-nickname +x` will give you a network vhost. the username is always visible.

Comment: Your hostname would be whatever you change 12.345.678.90 to. What network are you on? Some networks allow you to apply a permanent vhost that is activated every time you log into your nick.

Comment: Again I think kalaracey is your username, your shell username under which you are running the IRC client, not your host. Klar is your IRC Nick. Try either /username or if that doesn't work, create a user on your box called whatever you want to be and run the IRC client sudo'd as that user.

Comment: You can not hide the hostname in IRC. The host you are connected from must be visible. Otherwise where would the server send messages to?

Comment: It is my username sorry thank you @DaveC. Allow me to edit the question.

Comment: @DaveC The solution for irssi is `/set user_name <whatever>`. You can post an answer if you would like.

Comment: Downvote and no explanation? I edited the question to reflect the correction of my earlier mistake.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To change your username in irssi do:

```
/set user_name <whatever>
```

From within the client.

Answer (score 6):

A common technique for hiding the host name of a client is known as "irc bouncing". It involves getting a shell on a public server and connecting to an IRC network through that.

The parameter you want to change in your question is the user name. It's probably based on the email convention "user at host" aka bob@mail.com, for example. The username can usually be changed in the IRC client.

In irssi, the command is /set user_name [parameter]

E.G.:

```
prompt>>> /set user_name jaro


08:26 [server]
08:26 user_name = jaro

prompt>>> /connect irc.efnet.org

08:26 >  ! Irssi: Looking up irc.efnet.org
08:26 >  ! Irssi: Connecting to irc.efnet.org [208.51.40.2] port 6667
08:26 >  ! Irssi: Connection to irc.efnet.org established
(...)
08:26 >  ! Irssi: Your nick is owned by jaroslav  (rakhmato@flode.12313.pvv.ntnu.no)

prompt>>> /whois rakhmato

08:26 >  ! rakhmato (~jaro@54.44.202.84.customer.cdi.no)
08:26 >  !  ircname  : jaroslav
08:26 >  !  server   : irc.eversible.com (Eversible.com Internet Services)
08:26 >  !  hostname : 84.202.44.54
08:26 >  !  idle     : 0 days 0 hours 0 mins 21 secs (signon: Wed Mar 13 08:22:23 2013)
08:26 >  ! End of WHOIS
```

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer; unfortunately, I just realized that I was asking the wrong question. What I wanted to do was hide my username (`kalaracey`), not my hostname. I have upvoted you though.

Comment: I noticed that you were confused.

Answer (score 0):

For irssi at least, there're several name related settings need to be set:

```
/set nick ...
/set user_name ...
/set real_name ...
```

Note that they need to be set before connecting to a server.